# Selenium Python for creating a instagram liker bot

Tags: python, selenium, instagram, facebook-like, bots

I am using selenium for python to create a simple liker bot for instagram.
The idea is to like the first photo of a tag (in this example is "sunset").
It correctly selects the first photo but does not insert a like.

The code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from time import sleep

import User_data

chrome_options=Options()

chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
sleep(1)

browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(User_data.username)
browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(User_data.password)

sleep(1)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/button').click()

sleep(1)
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/sunset/")

sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//article/div[2]/div/div/div/a/div/div[2]").click()
sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button/span[contains(@class. 'glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7') ]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no instagram account.
but get login window when run this code in first photo selected state.

```
...
# here, first photo selected state
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button").click()
...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, but it did not work